# WebAuthn: Is it possible to filter passkey authenticators?

Tags: webauthn, fido, passkey

We use passkey in application and we want to restrict Passkey only by Google, Apple, Microsoft authenticators is it possible to do that? Because for example right now Android show me 1Password like a default authenticator.

Create call looks like this right now:

```
{
  "challenge": "nhkQXfE59Jb97VyyNJkvDiXucMEvltduvcrDmGrODHY",
  "rp": {
    "name": "CredMan App Test",
    "id": "credential-manager-app-test.glitch.me"
  },
  "user": {
    "id": "2HzoHm_hY0CjuEESY9tY6-3SdjmNHOoNqaPDcZGzsr0",
    "name": "helloandroid@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "helloandroid@gmail.com"
  },
  "pubKeyCredParams": [
    {
      "type": "public-key",
      "alg": -7
    },
    {
      "type": "public-key",
      "alg": -257
    }
  ],
  "timeout": 1800000,
  "attestation": "none",
  "excludeCredentials": [],
  "authenticatorSelection": {
    "authenticatorAttachment": "platform",
    "requireResidentKey": true,
    "residentKey": "required",
    "userVerification": "required"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible with creation parameters, by design.

Why do you want to restrict authenticators? What is a user supposed to do if they don't have access to an authenticator that you allow? Will you keep them on a phishable sign in method?

Comment: For example on Android we have Google Passkey, we check Google Services Availability and it's not available just prohibit to use Passkey on the device.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: I mean right now in android I can create Passkey using google account or for example 1Password account, how can I prohibit user to use 1Password for passkey creation?

Comment: You cannot prevent this via creation parameters. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because we don't believe some Passkey providers in terms of security and we wan't to have a whitelist

Comment: Then you can accept the passkey, and then perform some kind of secondary verification process that will satisfy your security requirements.

Comment: But for example in Android/iOS if user accept passkey it will be in the list(UI) and only user can delete it(in phone settings), so why should we create redundant passkey, it's really weird in terms of UX?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. However, not purely through a WebAuthn based create request like you have included in your question.

### FIDO2

WebAuthn in itself is a part of the FIDO2 standards. WebAuthn is the standard for how to implement FIDO2 in Web Applications and covers both server, referred to as Relying Party, and Clients. Authenticators are then covered by CTAP letting both communicate with each other.

### WebAuthn

How one triggers the create request for WebAuthn varies a bit but I'll assume we are doing this through `navigator.credentials.create(...)` in a browser. The rest of the answer doesn't really change depending on this.

As the `create` is a client side request you don't have a lot of restrictions possible to you, which is why it is impossible to actually purely restrict it through the client side, as faking client side data to circumvent security restrictions is in general trivial. So we must use the relying party to determine if we accept the key created or reject it.

So we would need to validate if we want to accept this on the Relying Party. First thing that would need changing in your request is that you'd require a attestation with the key being generated. This can be done by setting `Attestation` to direct in your request.

When the request finishes and you have generated a key you'll get back an `attestationObject` which first of all will include something called `attStmt`. The `attStmt` contains a certificate from the authenticator used to be able to validate its authenticity.

You also have another part of the response that is `authData` which in turn has `attestedCredentialData` which in turn has a `aaguid` field containing the unique identifier of the authenticator used.

With this info, your Relying Party can validate that the certificate is authentic and that the `aaguid` matches whatever whitelist you might have. Or doesn't match any blacklist you might have.

### FIDO2 Metadata Blob

Now the above is a bit limited as you'd need to maintain your own list of approved authenticators. However, FIDO Alliance also hosts a [metadata blob](https://mds3.fidoalliance.org/) . More info on the actual blob can be found [here](https://fidoalliance.org/metadata/).

The metadata blob itself contains all certified FIDO authenticators including the `aaguid` and the certificate for each. So validating that one truly used the authenticator would be as simple as validating the certificate towards the `aaguid`. The metadata blob is also maintained so if there is new authenticators from producers you trust/distrust the could easily be added to any whitelist/blacklist.

### TL;DR

Set your request to include attestation by changing `"attestation": "none"` to `"attestation": "direct"`. Then on your server side use the Fido [metadata blob](https://mds3.fidoalliance.org/) to validate the certificate and `aaguid` returned from the credential creation on your server and reject/approve them as fits your setup.

Comment: Is it possible if I use Apple/Google like a provider?

Comment: Depends on what you mean? You mean doing a direct login to your personal AppleID or directly into a Google account? Then no, neither Google nor Apple supports controlling this on standard users afaik. In this case you don't own the authentication server and Apple and Google in the end decide what security requirements they want and unless they expose it to clients, clients shouldn't be able to do things with it. My answer is based on you being the controller of the authentication server. That said, there are multiple services that expose this, Microsoft Azure AD does for example.

Comment: That said, I do not have access to a Google Workspace based account so unsure if an admin on that is allowed to limit which are viable there or not.

Comment: I just think that approach you mentioned is OK if I'm the owner of passkey provider, but in that case it's just a open(e.g. Apple) provider.

Comment: Correct, if you are a consumer of a 3rd party you are dependent on their customization options. Forcing them to have rules for you as a client is not very feasible at least. The behavior described would be very similar to you wanting to force your Google account to require 30 characters in your password instead of just choosing to have one. So if you don't own or have customization access to the provider, then you can't really enforce anything like specific authenticators, or if you wanted, password length.